# Print statements in UNNotification Content Extension

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, ios12

How do I execute print statements in a UNNotificationContentExtension?

Currently, when I run my application, I press run, but then when I open a notification content extension while I am still contected to Xcode, nothing shows. This makes it very difficult to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [image: Image of XCode panel.]

Likely, your app shows up in this area where you select the binary to build and the device to build it on.

2. [image: Image of XCode panel.]

Click your app and select the embedded binary that corresponds to your extension. 
If it does not show up here, see below.

3. [image: Image of XCode panel.]

Click run. It will first open up your main app. Then open up a notification with 3D touch or by pulling down on it when it arrives, and look at your console.

Note that when I selected the content extension embedded binary, it automatically selected my personal device.

If you do not see your target's embedded binary, go to your project.

[image: Image of project name in Xcode and where to click]

Click on your app.

[image: App shown next to targets after clicking on Xcode project]

In the "General" pane, scroll down to the "Embedded Binaries" and click the plus icon.

[image: Image of embedded binaries section in General tab of Xcode]